# jQuery - $(audio).on('ended' function()) only ever fires once, on first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I've just started on jQuery, and followed a tutorial to build an Audio player.

I want my audio, each time a song ends, to go to the next song and play it, automatically.

I checked an answer on here that followed the exact tutorial I did, but the answer didn't solve the problem.

I have marked the non working function with "BROKEN"

```js
var audio;

//hide pause button
$('#pause').hide();

//initialize first song
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');
    
    // Create Audio Object
    audio = new Audio('music/'+ song + '.mp3');
    
    // If no song loaded, show 0:00
    if(!audio.currentTime){
        $('#duration').html('0:00');
    }
    // otherwise get duration and show
    showDuration();
    
    // Get artist and song title
    $('#audio-player .audio-title').text('- ' + song);
    $('#audio-player .audio-artist').text(artist);
    
    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active-audio');
    element.addClass('active-audio');
}

// click playlist song
$('#playlist li').click(function(){
  audio.pause();
  initAudio($(this));
  audio.play();
  showDuration();
  $('#play').hide();
  $('#pause').show();
});﻿

// play button
$('#play').click(function (){
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});
// pause button
$('#pause').click(function (){
    audio.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});

// Next button
$('#next').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active-audio').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
    if($('#play').is(':visible')){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
    }
});

// Prev button
$('#prev').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active-audio').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
    if($('#play').is(':visible')){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
    }
});

// Volume Control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 100);
});

// Time Duration
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).on('timeupdate', function(){
        //get hours $ mins
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime)/60) %60;
        // Add 0 if < 10
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + ':' + s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = ((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
        });
}

// if song ended, go to next ==== BROKEN
$(audio).on('ended', function(){
    $('#next').trigger('click');
});

// click progress bar
$("#progressbar").mousedown(function(e){
    var leftOffset = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var songPercents = leftOffset / $('#progressbar').width();
 audio.currentTime = songPercents * audio.duration;
});
```

The function is supposed to trigger the click event on '#next' when the audio has ended. The click event for next works fine when clicked, and triggering works fine in the console, when listening for audio.on('ended'), it only ever fires once, and only ever fires on the first song.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

I have added in the html as a reference if needed

```html
<div id="audio-container">
    
    <!-- controls -->
    <div id="audio-player">
        <span class="audio-artist"></span>
        <span class="audio-title"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div id="audio-controls">
            <div id="play-pause">
                <button id="play"></button>
                <button id="pause"></button>
            </div>
            <div id="tracker">
                <div id="progressbar">
                    <span id="progress"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="duration"></div>
            <div id="volume-wrapper">
            <div id="speaker-icon"></div>
            <div id="volume-div">
                <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="audio-buttons">
        <a id="prev">«</a>
        <a id="next">»</a>
    </div>
    <!-- end controls -->
    
    <!-- input audio tracks here -->
    <div class="clearfix">
        <ul id="playlist">
            <li song="Dystopia" artist="Tesseract">
                <div class="track-no">01.</div>
                <div class="track-name">Tesseract - Dystopia</div>
                <div class="track-len">6:53</div>
            </li>
            <li song="Messenger" artist="Tesseract">
                <div class="track-no">02.</div>
                <div class="track-name">Tesseract - Messenger</div>
                <div class="track-len">3:34</div>    
            </li>
            <li song="Tourniquet" artist="Tesseract">
                <div class="track-no">03.</div>
                <div class="track-name">Tesseract - Tourniquet</div>
                <div class="track-len">5:57</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end input -->
    
</div>
```

Comment: When you go to next you call initAudio again which creates a new audio object which has no event attached to it. You need to attach your events when the new Audio object is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved the `ended` event listener into the initAudio() function. This should resolve the issue.

```js
var audio;

//hide pause button
$('#pause').hide();

//initialize first song
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');
    
    // Create Audio Object
    audio = new Audio('music/'+ song + '.mp3');
    
    // If no song loaded, show 0:00
    if(!audio.currentTime){
        $('#duration').html('0:00');
    }
    // otherwise get duration and show
    showDuration();
    
    // Get artist and song title
    $('#audio-player .audio-title').text('- ' + song);
    $('#audio-player .audio-artist').text(artist);
    
    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active-audio');
    element.addClass('active-audio');
  
  // if song ended, go to next ==== BROKEN
  $(audio).on('ended', function(){
      $('#next').trigger('click');
  });

}

// click playlist song
$('#playlist li').click(function(){
  audio.pause();
  initAudio($(this));
  audio.play();
  showDuration();
  $('#play').hide();
  $('#pause').show();
});﻿

// play button
$('#play').click(function (){
    audio.play();
    $('#play').hide();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});
// pause button
$('#pause').click(function (){
    audio.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
    showDuration();
});

// Next button
$('#next').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active-audio').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
    if($('#play').is(':visible')){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
    }
});

// Prev button
$('#prev').click(function(){
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active-audio').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
    if($('#play').is(':visible')){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('#pause').show();
    }
});

// Volume Control
$('#volume').change(function(){
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 100);
});

// Time Duration
function showDuration(){
    $(audio).on('timeupdate', function(){
        //get hours $ mins
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
        var m = parseInt((audio.currentTime)/60) %60;
        // Add 0 if < 10
        if(s < 10){
            s = '0'+s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + ':' + s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = ((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width',value+'%');
        });
}


// click progress bar
$("#progressbar").mousedown(function(e){
    var leftOffset = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var songPercents = leftOffset / $('#progressbar').width();
 audio.currentTime = songPercents * audio.duration;
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. This has been racking my brain for the past couple of hours.

Not too sure as to why it works though, haha :\

Comment: With the original code everything executes sequentially. First you `initAudio()` which creates a new `audio` object. Then the code runs sequentially down the page. At the bottom you attach your `ended` event. Everything at this point is good to go. When the `ended` event fires, you go call `initAudio()` again. Except this time when you call initAudio() the code does not run sequentially again it ONLY runs the code inside of `initAudio()` and replaces your `audio` object which does not have an event attached to it. By moving the `onEnded` into the function, it also gets called every time.

Comment: Another thing to look at is re-using the `audio` object simply by loading the new mp3 into it via `audio.src`, `audio.load()` and/or `audio.play()` Good luck and have fun with it. Also, if you don't mind, could you accept my answer? :)

Comment: Thanks heaps for the explanation. Having lots of fun playing around with this. Accepted and up'd ! :)

Comment: Happy to help out. :)